# Failed to resolve RecyclerView version 23

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I want to compile `RecyclerView` version 23.2.0 but there is a error.

> Failed to resolve com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0

My API version is 23. So what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **have to update** the SDK Manager.

[image]

Then use the latest

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView   version 23.0.1 and buildToolsVersion  '23.0.1'

Comment: RecyclerView `23.2.1` is the latest and the build tools `23.0.2` is the latest